# Where are Recovery Services in the new Azure Portal?

Tags: cloud, azure

Like the title says, I can't find Recovery Services in the new Portal

Answer (score 0):

As of 11/05/15 - The [Preview Portal](https://portal.azure.com/) simply redirects you to the [Classic Portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com) if you require ssetup/configuration of the recovery services.

You can only view your vaults in the preview portal but not the recovery services.